# How to access state variable from child to parent react-native?

Tags: react-native

I have a child component called shadows.
I want to get that data to my main parent component. How can I do that?
I know I can create variable in parent and pass it though component. But what about many nested components ?is there is other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Context API for that here is the official website of recat.[enter link description here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

and please provide your code for more details.